# How to understand tcl's return

Tags: tcl

I wanted to get the number of parameters of a proc from tcl and didn't want it to be printed in tclsh, so I used return

When I execute the following statement in the c environment

```
string tclCmd = "info args " + tclProcName + ";return";
    Tcl_Eval(interp, tclCmd.c_str());
    string res = Tcl_GetStringResult(interp);
```

The result of the execution is not printed in tclsh, but at the same time it is not possible to get the correct value

So I tried to write it like this：

```
string tclCmd = "info args " + tclProcName;
    Tcl_Eval(interp, tclCmd.c_str());
    string res = Tcl_GetStringResult(interp);
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "return");
```

This works, but I don't understand why it doesn't print out immediately when Tcl_Eval is executed, and the return statement is still valid afterwards

Comment: Looks like you're embedding tcl in a C++ program. tclsh has nothing to do with that, and stuff will only get printed if you do it yourself.

Comment: And why are you trying to use `return` at all? It only really makes sense inside a `proc`, code block or when `source`ing a file

Comment: The results of the command execution are printed when the code is run, I'm interested in when they are printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` command is not helpful at all there. It triggers an exception condition that comes out of `Tcl_Eval` as a return code of `TCL_RETURN` instead of `TCL_OK` (that is converted by the outer structure of a procedure, if that is relevant). Instead, you should call `Tcl_ResetResult(interp);` after you have finished with the return value (or have taken another reference to it) to put things back to how they were before your command implementation was invoked.